# How to call manual camera mode in Xamarin Forms Android Application

Tags: c#, xamarin, camera

I am using Xamarin.Media.Plugin with TakePhotoAsync.
I can take picture but only in basic camera mode while i need manual camera settings.

I've already tried Xamarin.Dynamsoft.Camera.Android,Leadtools.Camera.Xamarin, CrossPlatformLibrary.Camera.

How can i call manual camera mode in xamarin forms app?
Should I use any other nuget?
My target android version is Android 9.0 Api 28.

Comment: You can write Custom Renderer and customize the Camera.

Comment: Exactly, if you want to customize the camera, you will have to write OS-specific code (so at the very least Custom renderers) since it is not a Xamarin.Forms feature.

Comment: You can use `DependencyService` to call native method in Android Project .

Comment: Thanks for answers, i will probably use custom renderer and customize camera.
For now i am using diffrent default camera on the phone that my app will be developed and its something like bypass if you have to get manua settings and use Xamarin media plugin.